# Display checkbox next to the label in angular getting form Error

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

Team,

I am trying to display checkbox next to the label with my current scenario the check box is showing but i am getting an error.

This is my image reference how I need

[image]

This is my error

[image]

Here is my HTML code

```
                    <div class="fieldexplorer">
                    <form [formGroup]="fieldExplorer">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <select matNativeControl formControlName="panelName" (ngModelChange)="onItemDrop(group.formGroupName, $event)">
                                <option selected>Select Panel Name </option>
                                <option *ngFor="let formGroupNames of formData.groups">
                                    {{formGroupNames.formGroupName}}
                                </option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="fa fa-lock lock_field"></span>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </form>
                    <div class="sectionHeader_field">
                        Field Explorer Select All <input type="checkbox" formControlName="select">
                    </div>
                    <div *ngFor="let label of labels;" class="hoverselect" style="padding: 8px;border: 1px solid black;">
                        <span [ngClass]="(label.type=='Number'?'numberbefore':(label.type=='List'?'listbefore':'radiobefore'))">
                        </span> {{label.label}}
                        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="panel">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my TS code for that

```
  fieldExplorer: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    panelName: new FormControl(),
    panel: new FormControl(),
  });
```

Comment: The error is clear. You are using `formControlName` on form controls outside of a `form` with a `formGroup` directive. That is plain as day in the code you provide.

Answer (score 1):

**formControlName must be wrap inside *form* container only.**

Also, *ngModelChange* won't work here as you are using *Reactive forms*, it will work in template driven form.

To know more about how to handle change event in Reactive forms. Refer [this link](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/valuechanges-in-angular-forms/)

```
<div class="fieldexplorer">
                    <form [formGroup]="fieldExplorer">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <select matNativeControl formControlName="panelName" (ngModelChange)="onItemDrop(group.formGroupName, $event)">
                                <option selected>Select Panel Name </option>
                                <option *ngFor="let formGroupNames of formData.groups">
                                    {{formGroupNames.formGroupName}}
                                </option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="fa fa-lock lock_field"></span>
                        </mat-form-field>
                   
                    <div class="sectionHeader_field">
                        Field Explorer Select All <input type="checkbox" formControlName="select">
                    </div>
                    <div *ngFor="let label of labels;" class="hoverselect" style="padding: 8px;border: 1px solid black;">
                        <span [ngClass]="(label.type=='Number'?'numberbefore':(label.type=='List'?'listbefor`enter code here`e':'radiobefore'))">
                        </span> {{label.label}}
                        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="panel">
                    </div>

 </form>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors says that you have formControlName (parts of the form) outside of your `<form>` tag.

As you can see in your code you close your `</form>` and right after that you have more formControlNames, you need to wrap them aswell in the `<form`> tag